# Is there a shortcut to disconnect current bluetooth headphone on iPhone iOS 16.5

Tags: ios, bluetooth

I have a pair of bluetooth headphone (non apple).

If I leave them in a different room, still turned on, in order to disconnect them I:

1. Swipe down from top right to open menu
2. Long press blue tooth
3. Long press blue tooth (from list of connectivity options)
4. Tap the headphone name

Is that the fastest way?

Comment: Simply tap Bluetooth from the Control Center (or « menu »). No long-tapping is needed, just tap Bluetooth once and it should disabled Bluetooth and thus disconnect the device.

Comment: Do you want to keep other devices connected (like a watch)?  Or, do you just want to change where your output goes?

Comment: @thinkr that then disables all bluetooth devices

Comment: @Allan — I'd just like to disconnect the one device if possible.

Comment: You could just change the playback device using a simple shortcut (one liner).  I will remain on until it turns off by itself thus disconnecting.